# Find key with largest value in object

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object, data-structures

Let's say I have an object:

```
{Angry: "1.0", Fearful: "0.0", Happy: "0.0", Neutral: "0.0", Sad: "0.0"}
```

How to find the name of the property whose value is the largest? For example, here: the answer should be 'Angry', because its value '1.0' is the largest. Thank you for your inputs!

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Object.values( ... ), sort( ... ), and then the first element. Or Math.max.apply on the values. But since the values are strings, you'll need to parse the values into numbers if "9" has to be smaller than "10".

Answer (score 1):

```
var maxValue = 0;
var keyVal;
var object = {Angry: "1.0", Fearful: "0.0", Happy: "0.0", Neutral: "0.0", Sad: 
"0.0"};
for (var key in object) {
    let tempValue = parseFloat(object[key]);
    if(maxValue < tempValue) {
          maxValue = tempValue;
          keyVal = key;
    }
}

console.log(keyVal);
// expected output: "Angry"
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate through all properties of your JSON object and compare each value to see which one is the largest. Here is one way to achieve that:

```js
var guy1 = {Angry: "1.0", Fearful: "0.0", Happy: "0.0", Neutral: "0.0", Sad: "0.0"};
var guy2 = {Angry: "1.0", Fearful: "2.0", Happy: "0.0", Neutral: "0.0", Sad: "0.0"};
var guy3 = {Angry: "1.0", Fearful: "2.0", Happy: "4.0", Neutral: "0.0", Sad: "0.0"};

biggest(guy1);
biggest(guy2);
biggest(guy3);


function biggest(obj) {
   var max = 0;
   var emotion; 

   Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(e){
     if(max<Number(obj[e])) { max = Number(obj[e]); emotion = e; }
   });

   console.log(emotion, max);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `reduce` over your `Object.keys`, using an accumulator object to track the current highest value you found.

```js
const obj = {Angry: "1.0", Fearful: "0.0", Happy: "0.0", Neutral: "0.0", Sad: "0.0"}

const largest = Object.keys(obj).reduce((largest, key, i) => {
  obj[key] = parseFloat(obj[key])

  largest = obj[key] > largest.num
    ? { key, num: obj[key] }
    : largest

  return i === Object.keys(obj).length - 1 ? largest.key : largest
}, {
  key: null,
  num: 0
})

console.log(largest)
```

Comment: No output. forgot to console.log?

Comment: There's no console.log

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```js
let obj ={Angry: "1.0", Fearful: "0.0", Happy: "0.0", Neutral: "0.0", Sad: "0.0"}

let max= -Infinity;
let keyName;

for(let key in obj){
  let temp  = parseFloat(obj[key]);
  if(temp>max){
    max=temp;
    keyName = key 
  }
}

console.log("Max value is:-" ,max, "\nProperty Name is :-", keyName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get one result or many result of names, follow my code:

```js
var obj_1= {Angry: "1.0", Fearful: "0.0", Happy: "0.0", Neutral: "0.0", Sad: "0.0"};
var obj_2 = {Angry: "1.0", Fearful: "1.0", Happy: "0.0", Neutral: "0.0", Sad: "0.0"};
//get only one name max
var result1 = Object.entries(obj_1).sort((a,b)=>(b[1]-a[1]));
console.log(result1[0][0]);

//get list of names max
var list_names = [];
var result2 = Object.entries(obj_2).sort((a,b)=>(b[1]-a[1]));
result2 = result2.filter(current=>{
    if(current[1]==result2[0][1]){
        list_names.push(current[0]);
        return current;
    }
})
// console.log(result2);
console.log(list_names);
```